# Anyway to read NFS vhdx from Hyper-V under Windows?

Tags: nfs

Quick of it is: I have an Ubuntu 12.10 server instance, running under Hyper-V on Win 8. It has worked wonderfully for about 4 months.  Now, when I need to pull data back to Windows, inexplicably, it refuses to mount the swap drive, and will not acquire an IPv4 address from my local router.

Even though the system boots, and I can connect to it via the Hyper-V console, I cannot transfer data via scp, for instance. Also, connects via ssh also fail (e.g. hostname is unknown).

My question is: is there a way to get Win8 to be able to recognize and read NFS from VHDXs?

Apologies: want to add tags "Hyper-V" and "Windows 8".

Comment: The question whether a network file system can be read from a block device (image) makes little sense. If you cannot or do not want to repair the Ubuntu installation then you can get a live CD/DVD image and boot that. With that you can mount the virtual disk, and it should be easy to get network access (unless a hypervisor error is the problem).

Comment: This seems to be at least as much about windows as Linux, so it would probably do better on [SU]

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I think I've eliminated the hypervisor as a problem. I've a separate VM with near identical settings (excepting disk, memory & CPU allocations) with Ubuntu 12.10 desktop, and that VM is still working fine. The only thing I can think of is I'd done an apt-get update; apt-get upgrade about the last time I remember it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mounting a .vhdx file in Windows 8

If you're trying to mount a .vhdx file from Windows 8 you can do so by browsing in Windows Explorer to where the .vhdx file is located and simply right clicking on the file and selecting the option to "mount" it. Once you do so the filesystem should show up mapped to a drive letter on your host system.

[image: ss of mounting]

### Mounting a .vhdx file using DiskManagement

I came across this tutorial titled: [How to Manually Extract System Image Files Using Disk Management in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/17524-system-image-extract-files-using-disk-management.html), which shows an alternative method for mounting .vhdx files as HDD's. Using this method the .vhdx files will show up as actual drive letters in Explorer.

Open the "Power Users Tasks Menu" (Windows + X), and click/tap on Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc).

[image: ss of diskmanagement]

Then attach your .vhdx file as follows:

[image: ss of attach]

After selecting a drive letter you'll see the .vhdx file showing up as a mounted HDD:

[image: ss of mounted .vhdx]

### Mounting an NFS share from Windows

I found this tutorial which I think will give you what you want. It's titled: [HOWTO: Mount NFS shares under Windows 7](http://sagehacks.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/howto-mount-nfs-shares-under-windows-7/). Even though the directions are for Win7 I have no reason to believe they wouldn't work for Win8 as well.

To access an NFS share from Windows requires 4 things.

#### 1. NFS service

Depending on your distro these steps might be slightly different. Under Ubuntu I believe you'd do the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server nfs-common
```

Once complete you should have the NFS server and client software installed.

#### 2. export an NFS share

This is done on the computer that wants to provide an NFS share. You typically edit the file `/etc/exports` and add entries (one per line) for each directory you want to share via NFS.

```
# /etc/exports
/home 192.168.1.0/24 (rw, async, insecure)
/opt 192.168.1.2 (rw, async, insecure)
/usr/share *.op.us (ro, insecure)
```

The above says, directory I want to share (/home, /opt, & /usr/share), who has access to it (for /home, systems in the subnet 192.168.1.0, IP address 192.168.1.2 for /opt, and any system in the *.op.us domain for /usr/share). The last set of options in the parens (rw, async, insecure) are options that specify whether the share is read/write or readonly. You can read more about these options in the [NFS Howto](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/).

Once you're completed modifications to the exports file run the command `exportfs -a`. If things are working correctly you should be able to run the `showmount -e` command and see your exported NFS shares:

```
$ showmount -e localhost
Export list for localhost:
/home 192.168.1.0/24
/opt 192.168.1.2
/usr/share *.op.us
```

#### 3. NFS Client Services under Windows

To mount NFS shares in Windows you need to install the Client Services for NFS addon. This addon is part of the Services for Unix-based applications (SUA) which is only available in Windows 8 Enterprise. So either install it or you'll have to use a 3rd party application such as one of the following to get a Windows NFS client:

- [Nekodrive](http://code.google.com/p/nekodrive/)
- [Dokan](http://dokan-dev.net/en/)

You can read more about this over on SuperUser in the Q&A titled: [Ask Question
How do I mount an NFS share in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8).

#### 4. mounting NFS share

Now with all the software installed and configured you should be able to drop to a command windows (cmd.exe) and run the following command:

```
$ mount [options] //nfs-server-unc-name/share-name [drive letter]
```

#### References

- [FOLLOW-UP ON BACKUPS: MOUNTING A SYSTEM IMAGE](http://devhammer.net/blog/follow-up-on-backups-mounting-a-system-image)

Comment: I appreciate the answer - my problem is for reasons unknown, the networking on my Ubuntu VM has stopped working, and looking at the system logs, I'm not seeing anything apparent. I'm trying to mount the `.vhdx` directly - not mount the filesystem via a share (this will not work because my VM refuses to communicate to the outside world).

Comment: @NathanErnst - see update and let me know if that works out.

Comment: I will try and mount the drive as you have mentioned once I'm home from work, and will accept if it works.  I somehow got the networking in the VM to work last night; I just kept twiddling settings, and suddenly it worked (nearly as I can tell the settings that work are identical to what it was previously).

Comment: I tried all of the aforementioned steps, and I was not able to mount the drive into windows (perhaps because the filesystem was encrypted?), so at this time I cannot in good conscience accept the answer. (But, I have upvoted, regardless).

Comment: @NathanErnst - of course, not a problem. If it doesn't solve it, it doesn't make sense to accept. Can you describe what happened when you tried to mount the .vhdx file using my first method. Did it not show up as described or was it something else? Also is the filesystem encrypted? If it's  ext4 filesystem then this is something that you'd have to go out of your way to do, it's not normally there.

Comment: @NathanErnst - see my updates and let me know if the diskmanagment gives you any better luck.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, just now have time. Services for Unix is apparently no longer "available" from the control panel. There does appear to be a supported download at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35512  I will give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: that didn't work. Apparently my link above needs the SUA component, which was removed prior to Win8 RTM.

Comment: Additionally, following the above instructions, I am able to attach to the vhdx, but all actions on the individual partitions are disabled, excepting "delete volume" and "help".  I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer, because all of your steps were right, but MS has apparently decided to stop supporting it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NathanErnst - thanks! Still would like to help, I found this page with some suggestions on things to try: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b517845b-7474-4a27-8da7-c98d2bc8b03e/mount-vhd-in-windows-8-not-working